# How to auto-cc a system email account any time a user creates an appointment

Tags: exchange, outlook

I will not bother explaining my full architecture or reasons for wanting this in order to keep this question short:

**Is it possible to auto-cc a certain email account any time a Exchange user creates an appointment or meeting in his own calendar?**

- Is it possible using rules?
- Our Exchange 2007 server is outsourced, I cannot change the configuration or install plugins server-side
- Preferably, it still should work server-side, because users may use the Outlook client but also Outlook Web Access
- Is there any other way, perhaps using group policies?

My conclusion so far is that the only viable way to accomplish this is to build an Outlook add-on. The problem there is that it will need to be managed for thousands of desktop users and that the add-on will not work when using another client (OWA, mobile).

An alternative architecture could be to pull the information from the user's calendar on a scheduled basis. Given that we are talking about a lot of users, scalability is a major issue, this has also been confirmed by Microsoft.

Can you confirm that my thinking is correct or do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining an Outlook rule along the lines of:

```
Apply this rule after I send the message
uses the Meeting Request form
CC the message to X
```

Where X is the account you want to get copied.

Client-only, I'm afraid, so won't work in OWA. For that you'd need something like a transport rule, but since you can't touch the server, that's no good.